# Grouping ActiveRecord objects in batches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to return a group of products in my rails so that I can seperate them when I iterate in my view.

For example, if I have 13 products, I want the block in the view to put the first 7 on one row, break and put the next six on the next row (I'm using css to put a shelf under the products).

I've been experimenting with find_in_batches, but can't seem to get this to work (not even sure it's the appropriate method).

```
@shelves = Product.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 7) { |products| products }
```

I usually use group_by when I want to group based on a date, for example -- is there a way to use group_by to group by counts, instead of model attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find_in_batches.map` will give you a `no block` error. What you actually want is:

```
@shelves = Product.all.in_groups_of(7)
```

And if you'd like the last group to not have extra `nil` objects padding it out, try:

```
@shelves = Product.all.in_groups_of(7, false)
```

Of course, you'll want to replace `all` with a more sensible scope so you're not loading your entire list of database objects into memory :)

Answer (score 2):

You want an array of batches. Just mapping over the batches should do it.

```
@shelves = Product.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 7).map{|batch| batch}
```

Comment: `find_in_batches` is expecting a block. Try `Product.find_in_batches(:batch_size => 7) {|batch| batch }`